# Dns caching for sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, dns

I'm connecting to some websites through socks proxy server. In my case its very good to implement dns cache, so proxy don't need to resolve website's ip address. So, I performed DNS lookup, but don't know where to supply IP address. `mySocket.Connect` uses proxy's ip address so it isn't right place. I tried to place it in http header `GET http://11.22.33.44/index.html HTTP/1.1` - this doesn't work (even in browser) since website is on virtual hosting. It seems that `Host` header is right place for resolved ip address. Am I right? Will proxy resolve host name (since it's still there in GET header) or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is connect to the *SOCKS host*. You then instruct the SOCKS host to connect to the *IP address* that you have cached from DNS. When you are connected you send the HTTP headers (GET request and HOST header) that specify the *original domain name*.